# HTTP request taking 10+ seconds

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

Can anyone shed any light on why this code is taking so long to load?  I have tried it in a browser, and it only takes approx 4 seconds to load. Is there any way I can maybe disable loading of images in VBA web scrape?

(Note that the wait is on the `send` line, which takes in excess of 10 seconds to load, which to my mind is excessive?)

```
Sub FetchIndividualURL()
    Dim XMLHTTP as Object
    Dim HTMLdoc as Object
    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")

    URL = "http://www.gumtree.com.au/s-ad/lansvale/cars-vans-utes/2011-subaru-forester-x-grey-wagon/1106783884"

        With XMLHTTP
            .Open "GET", URL, False
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
            .send
            Set HTMLdoc = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
            HTMLdoc.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: my first load takes about 8 seconds.. i guess is it is due to loading javascripts. other than that loading in browser is faster because some items are cached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xmlhttprequest.send does not load images, nor js code. That's going to fetch the raw client side code of the resource referenced by the url. There is nothing that you could optimise in this code.

What you can do is to make the request asynchronous and have event handlers to take care of the incoming data. You can have more than one Xmlhttprequest objects downloading data in parallel.

There is a nice blog post on how to this properly in excel: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/10/09/async-xmlhttp-calls/

It describes how to make async calls, how and why to use a wrapping class for the event handlers.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info @Shadow. I'll see if I can implement it into my project

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not entirely true.

There are more request options to consider, which can greatly vary in efficiency depending on the website, none is the fastest or the slowest. Sometimes one of the requests regularly took over 10 seconds while the other only 2 seconds.

```
Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
```